# Monad Transformers in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, higher-kinded-types

I am working on using monad transformers in C#.
I would like to know if the following code I present, shows that I have understood this.
I am fairly new to this so any feedback / comments are really welcome.
This example is just for wrapping a maybe monad in a validation monad.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Monads
{
    public static class MaybeExtensions
    {
        public static IMaybe<T> ToMaybe<T>(this T value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return new None<T>();

            return new Just<T>(value);
        }
    }

    public interface IMaybe<T>
    {
        IMaybe<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f);

        IMaybe<U> SelectMany<U>(Func<T, IMaybe<U>> f);

        U Fold<U>(Func<U> error, Func<T, U> success);
    }

    public class Just<T> : IMaybe<T>
    {
        public Just(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;

        }

        public IMaybe<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f)
        {
            return f(value).ToMaybe();
        }

        public IMaybe<U> SelectMany<U>(Func<T, IMaybe<U>> f)
        {
            return f(value);
        }

        public U Fold<U>(Func<U> error, Func<T, U> success)
        {
            return success(value);
        }

        public IValidation<U, T> ToValidationT<U>()
        {
            return new ValidationMaybeT<U, T>(this, default(U));
        }

        private readonly T value;
    }

    public class None<T> : IMaybe<T>
    {
        public IMaybe<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f)
        {
            return new None<U>();
        }

        public IMaybe<U> SelectMany<U>(Func<T, IMaybe<U>> f)
        {
            return new None<U>();
        }

        public U Fold<U>(Func<U> error, Func<T, U> success)
        {
            return error();
        }

        public IValidation<U, T> ToValidationT<U>(U exceptionalValue)
        {
            return new ValidationMaybeT<U, T>(this, exceptionalValue);
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public Customer(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IValidation<T, U>
    {
        IValidation<T, V> Select<V>(Func<U, V> f);

        IValidation<T, V> SelectMany<V>(Func<U, IValidation<T, V>> f);
    }

    public class ValidationError<T, U> : IValidation<T, U>
    {
        public ValidationError(T error)
        {
            Error = error;
        }

        public IValidation<T, V> Select<V>(Func<U, V> f)
        {
            return new ValidationError<T, V>(Error);
        }

        public IValidation<T, V> SelectMany<V>(Func<U, IValidation<T, V>> f)
        {
            return new ValidationError<T, V>(Error);
        }

        public T Error { get; private set; }
    }

    public class ValidationSuccess<T, U> : IValidation<T, U>
    {
        public ValidationSuccess(U value)
        {
            Result = value;
        }

        public IValidation<T, V> Select<V>(Func<U, V> f)
        {
            return new ValidationSuccess<T, V>(f(Result));
        }

        public IValidation<T, V> SelectMany<V>(Func<U, IValidation<T, V>> f)
        {
            return f(Result);
        }

        public U Result { get; private set; }
    }

    public class ValidationMaybeT<T, U> : IValidation<T, U>
    {
        public ValidationMaybeT(IMaybe<U> value, T error)
        {
            Value = value;
            Error = error;
        }

        public IValidation<T, V> Select<V>(Func<U, V> f)
        {
            return Value.Fold<IValidation<T, V>>(() => new ValidationError<T, V>(Error), s => new ValidationSuccess<T, V>(f(s)));
        }

        ValidationError<T, V> SelectManyError<V>()
        {
            return new ValidationError<T, V>(Error);
        }

        public IValidation<T, V> SelectMany<V>(Func<U, IValidation<T, V>> f)
        {
            return Value.Fold(() => SelectManyError<V>(), s => f(s));
        }

        public IMaybe<U> Value { get; private set; }

        public T Error { get; private set; }
    }

    public interface ICustomerRepository
    {
        IValidation<Exception, Customer> GetById(int id);
    }

    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
    {
        public IValidation<Exception, Customer> GetById(int id)
        {

            if (id < 0)
                return new None<Customer>().ToValidationT<Exception>(new Exception("Customer Id less than zero"));

            return new Just<Customer>(new Customer("Structerre")).ToValidationT<Exception>();
        }
    }

    public interface ICustomerService
    {
        void Delete(int id);
    }

    public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
        {
            this.customerRepository = customerRepository;

        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            customerRepository.GetById(id)
                .SelectMany(x => SendEmail(x).SelectMany(y => LogResult(y)));


        }

        public IValidation<Exception, Customer> LogResult(Customer c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deleting: " + c.Name);
            return new ValidationSuccess<Exception, Customer>(c);
            //return new ValidationError<Exception, Customer>(new Exception("Unable write log"));
        }

        private IValidation<Exception, Customer> SendEmail(Customer c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Emailing: " + c.Name);
            return new ValidationSuccess<Exception, Customer>(c);
        }

        ICustomerRepository customerRepository;
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class MonadTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Testing_With_Maybe_Monad()
        {
            new CustomerService(new CustomerRepository()).Delete(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Another smaller sub question is if C# had higher kinded types could I just implement this class once (ValidationT) and it work for all other wrapped monads or is this incorrect?

Comment: this may help : http://mikehadlow.blogspot.fr/2011/01/monads-in-c-5-maybe.html

Comment: It only deals with single monads not composed monads.

Comment: This question looks more suitable to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7):

Almost, is the quickest answer.  Your `ValidationMaybeT` is storing the value of the `Maybe`, whereas a true monad transformer would have the behaviour of the `Maybe` and the `Validation` monad, and could modify the default behaviour of the wrapped monad if required.

This is a very manual way of doing it, which I wouldn't necessarily recommend, it gets very messy, very quickly.  C#'s lack of higher-kinded polymorphism will trip you up at every opportunity.

The closest I managed (even then it's not a proper monad transformer system) is with my library: [Language-Ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext)

There are 13 monads in the project (Option, Map, Lst, Either, Try, Reader, etc.), and I implement a standard set of functions for all of them:

```
Sum      
Count    
Bind     
Exists   
Filter   
Fold     
ForAll   
Iter     
Map      
Select
SeletMany
Where
Lift
```

These functions are the most useful in functional programming, and will pretty much allow you to do any operation needed.

So with all monads implementing these standard functions, they become a higher-kinded type.  Not that the compiler knows this, they are all just part of the same 'set'.

Then I wrote a T4 template to generate transformer functions as extension methods (they have a `T` suffix), for every combination of monad and function in the 'higher-kinded type'.

So for example:

```
var list = List(Some(1),None,Some(2),None,Some(3));
var total = list.SumT();
```

The code above results in `6`.  The definition for `SumT` is:

```
int SumT(Lst<Option<int>> self) => 
    self.Map( s => s.Sum() ).Sum();
```

`FilterT` for example will also work on the inner monad:

```
var list = List(Some(1),None,Some(2),None,Some(3));
list = list.FilterT(x => x > 2);
```

So the extension method route is a very good one.  Instead of creating a new type, use:

```
IValidation<IMaybe<T>>
```

Then provide the `Maybe` extension methods for `IValidation<IMaybe<T>>`

You can either do what I did and auto-generate from a standard set, or write them manually.  It then keeps your `Maybe` and `Validation` implementations clean and the bespoke transformer functionality separate.

If you're interested, this is the T4 template I used to generate the transformer methods (it's pretty ramshackle to be honest): [LanguageExt.Core/HKT.tt](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/HKT.tt)

And this is the generated code:  [LanguageExt.Core/HKT.cs](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/HKT.cs)

Before I did the HKT stuff above I did a similar method to what you're attempting, I have a monad called `TryOption<T>` which is a `Try` and an `Option`.  But with the new HKT stuff I can now write `Try<Option<T>>`.  The original implementation is [here](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/TryOption.cs):

Anyway, I hope that helps!